# Background image tiles horizontally or vertically instead of entire background

Tags: background-repeat

When I use x for background repeat, the tiles run horizontally along the top of the page, and when i use y they run vertically down the left side of the page.

I'm assuming there's something in my existing stylesheet that is causing a conflict, but I can't find it.

Here's the body code:

```
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;background-image:url('images/wallpaper_bg.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;">
```

Comment: Doh - I was thinking y meant yes and x meant no instead of x y coordinates!

Should be repeat-yes of course (ugh, a whole HOUR wasted)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking y meant yes and x meant no instead of x y coordinates!

Should be repeat-yes of course